# To check if object is on the left or right with respect to another object

Tags: flash, math, actionscript

A very simple math question. I am trying to implement a simple logic in one of my 2D flash football penalty shoot out games to check whether my player is on the right or left of a stable ball object. I would want to kick the ball only when the player is to the left of the ball and not on the right.

I am using ActionScript 3. I am trying to implement this logic in my main document class. I have two classes for the stable ball object and one for my player.

```
if(!moveLeft && !moveRight && canShootBall){
    for each(var footy:FootBall in footballArray){
        if(instance_Xena.hasCollided(footy) && checkIfPlayerLeft(footy)){
            trace("COLLISION WITH " +footy.getId());
            instance_Xena.playKickAnimation();
        }
    }
}

public function checkIfPlayerLeft(footy:MovieClip):Boolean{
      //check if the player is on the left side of the ball object here

}
```

So I tried calculating difference in their x positions like "instance_Xena.x - footy.x" but it would give the same positive number of course. If I can get a positive value for if the player is on the left and a negative value for if the player is to the right of the ball then it would solve my problem.

I remember using Vector3 dot product in 3D space to check if the player is in front or behind the enemy. But not sure if it applies here. How would I check it?

Comment: What have you tried? Why couldn't you answer this question yourself? In what way do you have access to the coordinates of the player/object? In what environment do you want to implement this functionality?

Comment: Sorry for being so ambiguous. I have edited my first post to be more clear now

Comment: I don't know ActionScript, but why do you always get a positive instead of +- number? What "same positive number" would you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I finally found a solution a solution and it works. I used something known as the Signed area of the triangle and it worked perfectly

Comment: You don't just check if the player x is less than the ball x?